# Expect an exception in Scala tests (no JUnit)

Tags: scala, scalatest

I had tests that should give null:

```
Object.someFunction(argUsedToGiveNull) should === (null)
```

But I've modified the function, and now I want the test to expect/assert the function given that value throws an IllegalArgumentException.

I'd like to do something like:

```
Object.someFunction(argNowThrowsException) should throw IllegalArgumentException
```

and note I am not using @Test JUnit structure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
an[IllegalArgumentException] should be thrown by Object.someFunction(argNowThrowsException)
```

Answer (score 4):

To test for an expected exception:

```
an [ExceptionType] should be thrownBy {
    Object.someFunction(argThrowsException) }
```

Note that the `evaluating`keyword used to be used for this but is now deprecated.